# Use more "natural" form to manipulate piecewise step functions in Matlab MuPAD?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, mathematical-expressions, mupad

I have the unit step function:

```
u0:= piecewise([-infinity < t and t < 0,0],[0 < t and t < infinity,1]):
```

Now I want to plot it at some point:

```
T:=1:;
plot(u0|t=t-T/2);
```

This works. But when I use a more natural expression:

```
T:=1:;
plot(u0(t-T/2));
```

it simply plots the original unshifted step function.

Is there any way to use the more simpler form when plotting the modified step function?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason that what you call the "more natural form" doesn't work, is because `u0` has not been defined as a [MuPad function/procedure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/programming-basics.html#programming-functions). In this case, you can create a procedure using the [`->` operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/proc.html):

```
u0 := t -> piecewise([-infinity < t and t < 0, 0], [0 < t and t < infinity, 1]):
```

Note that the above is equivalent to `u0 := t -> piecewise([t < 0, 0],[t > 0, 1]):` (I assume that you're aware that you've left `0` undefined). Then you should be able to evaluate:

```
T := 1:
plot(u0(t-T/2))
```

Because `u0` is now a function, your first form using the [`evalAt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/evalat.html) operator, `|`, must be altered to:

```
T := 1:
plot(u0(t)|t=t-T/2)
```