# Is this a bug in MuPAD?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, mupad

I have `u0` as step function (piecewise definition):

```
piecewise([0 < t, 1], [t < 0, 0])
```

Now I compute:

```
int(u0(t)|t=k, k=-infinity..t)
```

which gives

```
piecewise([0 < t, t], [t <= 0, 0])
```

In a textbook I found the answer:

```
piecewise([0 =< t, t], [t < 0, 0])
```

Is this a bug in MuPAD?

Comment: lol why thfvuck i got -2 ?

Comment: A possible reason you may have been down voted is that your code is not runnable. Define the `u0(t)` function as I suggest in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27750287/2278029). Your title is also very poor and wouldn't help anyone find your question to answer their own future query. This is a community. Don't just think of yourself when asking. This is your second question in a row that you've suggested there might be a bug rather than the more likely case of you making a mistake or not understanding how to use MuPAD (see [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor)).

Comment: u0 definition is in the first paragragph lol

Comment: No it is not. That is not runnable code because the *the code itself* does not define `u0`. If one tries to run your first two lines of code as written they will get an error.

Comment: if u cant define before like I explained u0 then u have no business trying to understand my question , I am sorry , but you are trolling

Comment: *I* understand what you mean, but maybe your down voters didn't (you yourself didn't know how to define `u0` as a function/prcedure in [own previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27742672/2278029)). I'm sorry that you took offense, but it's not very nice to accuse someone who's trying to help you improve your question and help other reproduce your issue of being a troll. We try to be nice to each other and be helpful on this site. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

I does not matter if you use `f(t)=t` or `f(t)=0` for t=0. In both cases the result is `0`